# Python 3: How do I find a char in a list and get the number of occurrences and position?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of letters, I want to see if these letters appear in a list of states. If they do appear, I want to know which letter appears and in which position it appears. I want to store it in a variable so I can then compare it to another string. Below is my example code:

```
    letters = ['a','b','c','d','e']
    states = ['minnesota','new york','florida']
    found_states = [] 

    for letter in letters:
        for state in states:
            if letter in state:
            found_states.append(state)
            #Here instead of appending to a list
            #I want to find the position of each letter
            #without losing the letter itself
            found_letter = {'e':4,'a':8} #desired result for minnesota
            #i want to use found_letter variable to perform additional
            #if statements
    print(found_states)
```

Comment: What if the letter appears twice, like `'a b a'`?

Comment: then i would want a:1, b:2, a:3 etc.

Comment: but you can associate only **one** value to a key, so a key cannot appear twice in a dictionary...

Comment: what it didnt have to be a dictionary? for example the word 'amaze', could i get a variable x = 'aae' instead and deal with losing the position? My main goal is to get the letters in the names and not lose their order

Comment: possibly a key with a list of indexes? So 'amaze' would look like [{'key':'a', 'index': {0,2} }, {'key':'m', 'index: {1} } ...] Then you have all your index for each unique char, and can even run a length on index if you want to know how many occurrences there are of that letter in the word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)!

> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists. Common
>   applications are to make new lists where each element is the result of
>   some operations applied to each member of another sequence or
>   iterable, or to create a subsequence of those elements that satisfy a
>   certain condition.

For every s in states, for every character, check if its present in your letters list. If found, then you can get the index and the character in a list without losing its order!

```
>>> [(s,[(index,c) for index,c in enumerate(s) if c in letters]) for s in states]
[('minnesota', [(4, 'e'), (8, 'a')]), ('new york', [(1, 'e')]), ('florida', [(5, 'd'), (6, 'a')])]
```

If you break down the list comprehension,

```
>>> [s for s in states] 
['minnesota', 'new york', 'florida']

>>> [[c for index,c in enumerate(s)] for s in states] 
[['m', 'i', 'n', 'n', 'e', 's', 'o', 't', 'a'], ['n', 'e', 'w', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'r', 'k'], ['f', 'l', 'o', 'r', 'i', 'd', 'a']]

>>> [[(index,c) for index,c in enumerate(s)] for s in states]
[[(0, 'm'), (1, 'i'), (2, 'n'), (3, 'n'), (4, 'e'), (5, 's'), (6, 'o'), (7, 't'), (8, 'a')], [(0, 'n'), (1, 'e'), (2, 'w'), (3, ' '), (4, 'y'), (5, 'o'), (6, 'r'), (7, 'k')], [(0, 'f'), (1, 'l'), (2, 'o'), (3, 'r'), (4, 'i'), (5, 'd'), (6, 'a')]]

>>> [(s,[(index,c) for index,c in enumerate(s)]) for s in states]
[('minnesota', [(0, 'm'), (1, 'i'), (2, 'n'), (3, 'n'), (4, 'e'), (5, 's'), (6, 'o'), (7, 't'), (8, 'a')]), ('new york', [(0, 'n'), (1, 'e'), (2, 'w'), (3, ' '), (4, 'y'), (5, 'o'), (6, 'r'), (7, 'k')]), ('florida', [(0, 'f'), (1, 'l'), (2, 'o'), (3, 'r'), (4, 'i'), (5, 'd'), (6, 'a')])]
```

To make access of elements much easier, you can use dict comprehension!

```
>>>res =  {s:[(index,c) for index,c in enumerate(s) if c in letters] for s in states}
>>> print res
{'minnesota': [(4, 'e'), (8, 'a')], 'new york':[(1, 'e')], 'florida':[(5, 'd'), (6, 'a')]}
```

So when you wan to access for one state say 'florida'

```
>>> print res['florida']
[(5, 'd'), (6, 'a')]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Are these just list inside of list?

Comment: I've added the edits. Hope it helps you to understand the code!

Comment: How would I access the characters, for instance for minnesota. If I wanted to access the 'e' and the 'a', what kind of statement would I use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
found_letter = {}
i = 0
for letter in letters:
    i=i+1
    for state in states:
        if letter in state:
            found_states.append(state)
            if letter in found_letter:
                found_letter[letter].append(i)
            else:
                found_letter[letter] = []
                found_letter[letter].append(i)
print(found_states)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to get a list of all indices of the letter

```
state = 'ohio'
letter = 'o'
occurences = [i for i, c in enumerate(state) if c == letter]
```

Comment: occurences = [i for i, c in enumerate(states) if c == letters]
print(occurences) I get back an empty list

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lot of approaches :)

```
list_of_letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'n']
states = ['minnesota', 'new york', '

    def search_letters(letters):
        found_states = {}
        for letter in letters:
            for state in states:
                for i, char in enumerate(state):
                    if char in letter:
                        found_states.setdefault(state, []).append(letter + ":" + str(i + 1))
        return found_states
```

After you use:

```
print search_letters(list_of_letters)
```

You will receive something like:

```
{'new york': ['e:2', 'n:1'], 'florida': ['a:7', 'd:6'], 'minnesota': ['a:9', 'e:5', 'n:3', 'n:4']}
```

So you will receive something like you described in the description of this issue.
Of course you can sort the lists of a particular dictionary key, if you want.

Comment: your numbers are not correct. 0 starts indexes in most everything I know of

Comment: But as I understood, author needs position of each letter in a particular word. Because python counts every iteratable variable from zero, I add 1 to each index of letter inside the word.
To summing up, if I have a word: "gant" and I'm searching of the letter: "g", I would expect to receive 1 instead of 0. If the author prefer to receive python's indexes, just delete 1 from str(i + 1)) statement.

Comment: yes and position starts at 0. so the first occurrence of e in 'New York' is 1. That is the index= position. Ex. try this code `print('New York'[2])` you will get w not e. Also look at his found letter examples and the selected answer examples; you see the same as I am saying, not what you are.

Comment: Edward :) Look at my code again, I added 1 to index to receive proper values. I pasted output from the trace, so this is proper code.

Comment: why would you have someone add +1 to index? Especially when they will be using it later on "i want to use found_letter variable to perform additional if statements", because then you just have to then delete 1.